# Call Bootstrap Tabs From Multiple Locations

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to add links to the top of a page to access data-tabs, in addition to them working in the normal tab section of the Twitter Bootstrap examples.

I have the following basic tabs through Bootstrap:

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
    <li><a href="#news" data-toggle="tab" class=""><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-comment"></span> Latest News</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#people" data-toggle="tab" class=""><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span> The People</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#agenda" data-toggle="tab" class=""><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span> Agenda</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#messages" data-toggle="tab" class=""><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plane"></span> Accommodations</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#faq" data-toggle="tab" class=""><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-comment"></span> FAQ</a>
    </li>
</ul>
<!-- End tabs -->
```

A sample of content here:

```
<div class="tab-content">
    <div class="tab-pane active" id="news">
        <div class="span5">
            <ul class="green-checks">
                <li>
                    <div class="panel panel-info">Information coming soon!</div>
                </li>
                <!--<li><cite>May 24, 2013 &mdash; </cite>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</li>-->
            </ul>
        </div>
```

What I'm trying to do is call the tabs via the header navigation as well as from the tabbed-section itself. Duplicating the code like this isn't working:

```
<li class="menu-item"><a href="#people" data-toggle="tab" class="">The People</a></li>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Edit** - updated to include scroll to tab after click.

---

Simulate a tab-switch by `click()` instead :

```js
function tabClick(tab) {
    $('a[href='+tab+']').click();
    $(tab).animate({scrollTop:0}, 'fast');
}
```

...

```
<li class="menu-item">
   <a href="#" onclick="tabClick('#people');return false;" data-toggle="tab" class="">The people</a>
</li>
```

Comment: Thanks for the help.  That does change the tab.  Now I just need to add code to have the page jump down to where the tab is at.